# Spring JPA repository is not working with two transaction managers

Tags: spring, jpa

I am using two transaction managers in my code. One is marked as primary. Complete configuration is using Spring annotation.
Table that I am trying to update using NON-primary transaction manager is not able to save data in the database. If I mark the same transaction manager as primary then it starts inserting data into database.

In case of non primary transaction, I am getting below error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:157)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.ashish.business.CreditCardManagementImpl.addCreditCardUser(CreditCardManagementImpl.java:44)
    at com.ashish.business.CreditCardManagementImpl.addCrCardCustomerData(CreditCardManagementImpl.java:30)
```

My code is present in the following location
https://github.com/ashismo/repositoryForMyBlog/tree/master/spring/SpringJPARepoDistributedTransaction

In my code, **com.ashish.appConfig**  package has three classes called **AppConfig.java, CreditCardTransactionConfig.java and DebitCardTransactionConfig.java**. Where **AppConfig** has included other two classes and **CreditCardTransactionConfig.java** has **NON** primary transaction manager configuration

I am running this code from junit file. And the above mentioned error is coming as soon as I am trying to do **creditUserDetailRepository.flush()**;. If I do not have this line in my code then I am not getting any error but data is not getting inserted into the table.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DebitCardTransactionConfig` class you have annotated the `debitEntityManagerFactory` method with the `@Primary` annotation. That annotation means, that this instance should be used whenever there are multiple candidates for autowiring based on type. You are creating the `PlatformTransactionManager`s like this:

```
@Bean(name="creditTransactionManager")
@Qualifier("creditTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager creditTransactionManager(
            EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    //...
}
```

This means, that Spring should choose the `EntityManagerFactory` automatically. Hence, both transaction managers are handed the debit entity manager factory.

What you should do for a quick fix, is to change the declaration of the `creditTransactionManager` like this:

```
@Bean(name="creditTransactionManager")
@Qualifier("creditTransactionManager")
//  @Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager creditTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(creditEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

As calling a different `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class means retrieving the instance from scope, this should work without problems. Unfortunately, I was unable to test this. See side notes.

**SIDE NOTES**
Here are some offtopic notes about your code.

- Your `CreditCardTransactionConfig`, and `DebitCardTransactionConfig` classes are very simillar. Consider extracting a super class that would eliminate most of the boilerplate.
- The bean name is taken from the name of the `@Bean` annotated method. You do not need to specify it in the `@Bean` and `@Qualifier` annotations.
- While it is a good idea to share a repository so that anyone can clone your code and test it, I was unable to run your test as it expects a MySQL database. Consider using an in-memory database like H2 for experimenting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Apokralipsa. It worked for me. Also thanks for your suggestion. I shall implement the same in my github code.  
I wanted to check with you one thing(as point number 2 in your side note) i.e. if I do not use any qualifier then how my repositories will know which transaction manager and entity manager to be used?

Comment: You used the `@EnableJpaRepositories` to specify the entity manager factory and transaction manager for entities located in a specific package and it will still work that way. The name of the method you annotated with `@Bean`, the name attribute of that annotation and the value attribute of the `@Qualifier` annotation serve the same purpose in your case, so you are just setting the same name three times.